# Objects Retrieved from List<T> Appear to Be Copies, Not References

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In my code, I have a class that maintains a number of lists. We'll focus on one of them for the moment, since it's the one that highlighted the problem.

```
internal List<Badge> Badges { get; private set; }
```

In the code, I add `Badge` instances to this list when an XML document is parsed. Later, I want to update the individual instances in the list so I can have the data written back out to XML. Because of the way the data's XML structure differs from the original file structure, there's some hocus-pocus involved, but that's largely mapped out. The surprise came when I attempted to update an item in the `List<Badge>`.

Specifically, the problematic code is here:

```
// Get the current badge from the loaded XML data, so we can update it.
var currentBadge = this.GameData.GetCurrentBadge();
```

I always get a valid badge back. The surprise, as I've come to find out, is that this simple test always fails:

```
var result = this.GameData.Badges.IndexOf(currentBadge);
```

`result` always evaluates to -1, indicating that the object doesn't exist in the collection. (EDIT: Updating the properties on `currentBadge` has no effect whatsoever on the contents of the matching item in `this.GameData.Badges`.) Which leads me to conclude that *I'm getting a copy of my object back, and not a reference, as I would have expected.*

For the inquisitive, the code to retrieve badges from the GameData class is included below. I have a sneaking suspicion that this is a documented behavior of generic lists, and that this is the first time I've stumbled across it. If so, I'm in for a very rude awakening. If it's not, I'd really like to know why my objects are coming back "disconnected" from their originals.

```
private Badge GetCurrentBadge()
{
    var badgeItem = GetCurrentBadgeItem();
    if (badgeItem != null)
    {
        return this.GameData.GetBadgeByText(badgeItem.Text);
    }
    return null;
}

private MenuOption GetCurrentBadgeItem()
{
    if (!(this.currentItem is MenuOption && 
         (this.currentItem as MenuOption).IsLocked))
    {
        return null;
    }

    MenuOption result = null;
    var children = this.currentMenu.Children;

    for (var n = children.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        var child = children[n] as MenuOption;
        if (child == null || !child.IsLocked)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!child.Text.StartsWith(" "))
        {
            result = child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

UPDATE: Per request, GetBadgeByText, which comes from the GameData class.

```
internal Badge GetBadgeByText(string badgeText)
{
    foreach (var badge in Badges)
    {
        if (badge.Text.ToLower() == badgeText.ToLower())
        {
            return badge;
        }
    }

    return null;
    // var b = (from l in Badges
    //         where l.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(badgeText.ToLower())
    //         select l).FirstOrDefault();
    //return b;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried it both with and without Linq, just to eliminate that as the culprit. Changing the implementation had no noticable effect.

And for the record, all the objects in this application are CLASSES. No structs anywhere.

UPDATE #2: The Badge class.

```
internal class Badge
         : GameDataItem
{
    public Badge()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public string AuthId { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsAccoladePower { get; set; }

    public string RequiredBadges { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }

    internal string ToXml()
    {
        var template = "<Badge value=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\" category=\"{2}\" authid=\"{3}\" requires=\"{4}\" accolade=\"{5}\" description=\"{6}\" />";
        return string.Format(template,
            this.Value,
            this.Text,
            this.Category,
            this.AuthId,
            this.RequiredBadges,
            this.IsAccoladePower,
            this.Description);
    }
}
```

And just in case someone asks for it, the base class:

```
internal class GameDataItem
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this._text;
        }
        set
        {
            this._text = value.Replace("&lt;", "<")
                         .Replace("&gt;", ">")
                         .Replace("&amp;", "&");
        }
    }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text + "=\"" + Value + "\"";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does GetBadgeByText look like?

Comment: What is `this.GameData.GetBadgeByText` doing?

Comment: Is `Badge` a struct or a class?

Comment: Good question dbt, I wanna know the same.

Comment: Is Badge a struct, instead of a class? If Badge is a value type instead of a reference type, then it obviously wouldn't be modifying the instance in the List<Badge> instance. Can you post the Badge type definition?

Comment: Are you sure that `GetCurrentBadge` is not returning `null`?  That would explain why `IndexOf` is returning -1...

Comment: I have, indeed, verified that it's not null. Stepping through the code proved it. I set a watch on the variable, and can observe that the variable is nonnull and contains the data I expect. But when I attempt to match it up to the corresponding object in the List<Badge> that it came from, IndexOf reports that it can't be found.

Comment: Not to get all Skeet-ish on you, but you should really put together a small and complete program that illustrates the problem rather than posting large bits of unrelated code.  In fact, I suspect that if you isolate the List<T> issue (which is *definitely* not copying your objects), the real problem will become obvious to you.

Comment: Yes, that's very unusual, and `List<T>` does not copy objects at all, so this is a bit weird.

Comment: @tnyfst: My apologies. I didn't honestly think I'd need to show this much code, until folks started asking for it. I figured the solution was (as usual) something obvious and painfully stupid and would have been pointed out to me by now. That's usually the way it works. Apparently, it hasn't turned out that way this time. Hence, all the piecemeal code.

Comment: Are you sure that your list isn't being re-populated in between these calls?   You haven't posted the complete code for this class...

Comment: The list does not get wiped out and rewritten, if that is what you mean. It is initialized when the class is constructed, filled as the XML data is parsed, and *never* cleared. (Well, not until the application shuts down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like this has something to do with `MenuOption`'s implementation of `Equals(object)`.  The `IndexOf()` method of the `List<>` will use `Equals(object)` when deciding what to return.

Comment: I've not overridden anyone's implementation of Equals.

Comment: You may have actually hit the nail on the head. I wrote an override for Badge.Equals, and IndexOf is now returning a valid index. The question now is, will updates to currentBadge be reflected in the collection when I update its properties?

Comment: Success. I would never have thought to consider Equals as the culprit. Kudos, good sir. Kudos.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  Looking at your edits, I'd also suggest you change "if (badge.Text.ToLower() == badgeText.ToLower())" into something that uses String.Compare(). What you have will create a lot of garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. You are putting a copy of the object in the list.  (`List<T>` does not clone objects or do any other sort of trickery.)
2. `Badge` is a struct, not a class, which means that you don't actually hold references to it since it would be a value type.
3. There's some copying going on elsewhere in code you haven't pasted.

Answer (score 0):

A generic List<T> does not copy objects. You add references to it, and the same references comes out - so there must be another problem in the code.

How is GetBadgeFromText implemented ? Does it read directly from the `Badges` List ?

Is this a web app ? If yes, does your List live between requests, or is it deserialized and serialized on each request (this could also be the problem).

Comment: GetBadgeByText originally used LINQ to select the matching badge from the List<Badge>; when I was stumped by the behavior, I changed it to use a simple foreach. No change was observed. And it's a Windows Desktop app.